# Better way for many components?

Tags: c#, layout

I have coded a system where each 'Player' class requires 5 components (could be more in the future, up to 10, 20 maybe even 30, once we add more and more features). What I want some advice on is a better way of creating these components, I am not saying that my current way is bad, I am just looking for anyone who could throw a fresh idea my way, to give my application a much better feel component wise.

My current way:

```
_searchesComponent = new PlayerSearchComponent(_playerConnection);
_searchesComponent.InitializeComponent();

_ignoreComponent = new PlayerIgnoreComponent(_playerConnection);
_ignoreComponent.InitializeComponent();

_effectsComponent = new PlayerEffectComponent(_playerConnection);
_effectsComponent.InitializeComponent();

_itemComponent = new PlayerItemComponent(_playerConnection);
_itemComponent.InitializeComponent();

_logComponent = new PlayerLogComponent(_playerConnection);
_logComponent.InitializeComponent();
```

Here is the base layout of one of my component classes:

```
namespace MyApp.Players.Players.Effects
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Components;
    using NLog;

    internal sealed class PlayerIgnoreComponent : IDisposable, IComponent
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private readonly PlayerConnection _playerConnection;
        private List<int> _ignores;

        public PlayerIgnoreComponent(PlayerConnection playerConnection)
        {
            _playerConnection = playerConnection;
            _ignores = new List<int>();
        }

        public void InitializeComponent()
        {
            using (var databaseConnection = Server.Database.NewDatabaseConnection)
            {
                var playerId = _playerConnection.SelectColumnInt("id");

                databaseConnection.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM `user_ignores` WHERE `user_id` = @userId");
                databaseConnection.AppendParameter("userId", playerId);

                using (var reader = databaseConnection.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        _ignores.Add(reader.GetInt32("ignore_id"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        private void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposing)
            {
                return;
            }

            _ignores.Clear();
            _ignores = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Fields:

```
private PlayerConnection _playerConnection;
private PlayerEffectComponent _effectsComponent;
private PlayerSearchComponent _searchesComponent;
private PlayerIgnoreComponent _ignoreComponent;
private PlayerClothingComponent _clothingComponent;
```

Here is IComponent:

```
namespace MyApp.Players.Players.Components
{
    public interface IComponent
    {
        void InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Any performance enhancement comments, answers or anything just to overall improve the code is also welcome.

Comment: Why are the fields listed in a separate code block? Can the question be edited to include the class module as it appears in your IDE?

Comment: Use a DI container

Comment: Please post all of two.  Right not you do nothing with private List<int> _ignores;

Answer (score 3):

Because the class is `sealed`, your `IDisposable` implementation is over-complicated. The whole entire point of the `disposing` flag is to make sure unmanaged resources get cleaned up correctly *even if a class inherits this type and overrides* `Dispose`... but your method isn't `virtual`, so it's only ever called/callable with `Dispose(true)`.

Scrap that, keep it simple:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _ignores.Clear();
    _ignores = null;       
}
```

Actually, if you're using that type correctly, then you gain nothing from explicitly clearing the internal list and `null`ing it up - the instance is [in theory] about to get collected anyway; `IDisposable` is making your class much more complex than it needs to be.

Typically you'd make a class implement `IDisposable` when it's holding on at instance level to a reference that implements `IDisposable` itself, which does not appear to be the case here (unless `PlayerConnection` has implications that aren't in your post) - disposing a `List<int>` is pure overkill.

Moreover, calling `Dispose` twice should have no ill effect on the calling code, but in your case it throws a rather surprising `NullReferenceException`, and then you could very well call `InitializeComponent` again... without getting an expected `ObjectDisposedException` (you get another `NullReferenceException` instead).

The `IComponent` interface seems uncalled for, given how the callers *seem* to only be calling the concrete types' implementations of the `InitializeComponent` method.

The implementation is tightly coupled with some static/global-scope database-interacting service, which makes it untestable.

---

If all "components" load things from a database, it seems you need to look into the *repository* pattern, and possibly the *unit of work* as well. Consider using *dependency injection* to decouple your implementation from its dependencies, and avoid `static` / global-scope objects in OOP as a general rule of thumb.

Comment: I'd argue the *disposing* (not *disposed*) flag is not for inheritance but to differentiate between when it's called manually and when called from the finalizer thread, to alter the method's logic. Hence the standard pattern of `Dispose(true)` when called manually, and `Dispose(false)` from the destructor. Of course in this case it's irrelevant since it is only ever called manually (if at all).

Comment: @eurotrash correct - but there's no finalizer involved either; and the [Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx) is pretty clear: "**DO** declare a `protected *virtual* void Dispose(bool disposing)` method to centralize all logic related to releasing unmanaged resources." - that `virtual` overload is *specifically* so inherited types can hook into the object's disposal without accidentally leaving stuff alive in the base class. The parameterized overload is `virtual` in every implementation I've seen, which makes it irrelevant for a `sealed` class.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Got to say that when I implement `Dispose(bool disposing)` I always make it private (can't remember ever implementing a Disposable class where I wanted to allow inheritance, much less allow Dispose to be overridable). Useful page on the Dispose pattern, bookmarked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `SELECT *` if you are only using one column

Comment: @Tushar Don't SELECT * if you are only using one column